# Как посчитать количество дней, месяцев, годов, имея даты в таблице mysql

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

| id | date | price |

Даты бывают разные:

```
2022-08-16 18:03:04
2022-08-16 18:08:03
2022-08-10 13:25:39
2022-08-20 13:39:25
```

Я не могу найти как их посчитать.

Нужно:

1. Дней - 3
2. Месяцев 1
3. Годов - 1

Я просто не могу ни чего придумать, а в интернете только о том как получить между датами количество дней. Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: Выделить отдельные компоненты, потом агрегировать.

Comment: *в интернете только о том как получить между датами количество дней.* https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Смог после некого размышления.
Не знаю хорошо ли получилось, но у меня как я хотел, так и работает.

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT DAY(date)) as date FROM table
```

Я просто не учитывал дубликаты, поэтому `count` считал все мои дубликаты дат.
Но вот минус в том что, если года, месяца, разные, а дни одинаковые, то они их засчитывать не будут а удаляться как дубликаты.

Я только что попробовал использовать так:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT DATE_FORMAT(date, '%Y-%m-%d')) as date FROM table
```

Теперь учитывается полная дата.
Больше ни как не смог придумать